# How to correctly ground a 12v device with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiringpi

i have a (i think) very simple question.
For my Raspberry i've bought a coin acceptor which needs a 12v power supply,
the wiring is like this:
[image: wiring]

now i'm quite unsure how i need to connect the Ground of the coin acceptor, do I need to connect it to the "GND" of the pi or to the "-" of the power supply?

Thy

UPDATE:

Could i work like this?

[image]

UPDATE 2:
Here is another setup with the exact same coin acceptor, but i'm not quite sure about that.

https://jalibu.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/advice_machine.jpg

The Product is a CH-926: https://www.amazon.de/Sintron-M%C3%BCnzpr%C3%BCfer-Acceptor-Selector-Laundromat/dp/B00C16P03I

Edit: Any help?

Comment: Simply add relay in the middle device between yellow pin and GND. The relay will short circuit GPIO1 to GND of the Pi. GND of middle device is connected to minus.

Comment: Okay but i dont want to short circuit the GPIO1 of the device in the middle :D

Comment: Your updated diagram should work

Comment: @Jon Not sure whether GPIO1 will "like" 12V. Maybe a resistor will be necessary. I am not expert in electronics but yellow wire will transfer 12V to 5V-running-Pi.

Comment: @AppleWeb If you need high level on GPIO1 instead of 0, you can connect GPIO1 to Vcc with the relay instead of GND.

Comment: @i486 right, you are correct, I was assuming that the 12V requiring device still operates on 5v signals. We don't yet have enough information about GPIO lines.  If it is a microprocessor, it would be pretty rare for it to be 12v logic. The grounding is all correct.

Comment: @AppleWeb tell me more about the communication between GPI01 and the device that requires 12V power. Which direction is the communication? What's the voltage of the communication?

Comment: @Jon I guess the yellow signal is "coin inserted". And Pi has to count it.

Comment: @AppleWeb please edit your post with the make model of the *coin acceptor* or a link to the product's description.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your answers, i added the coin acceptor to the main post.

Comment: In the future, this sort of question is probably better suited to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Okay :) @Jon, btw i also have two devices connect to the GROUND pin of the pi which dont require 12v "ground" could this be a problem if the ground of the pi is connected to the power supplys ground?

Comment: It is ok to share a common ground reference between the devices and power supplies. Unfortunately the documentation for that coin sensor is too sparse for me to tell you how to use the signal output. Someone more familiar with these may be able to help.

Comment: @Jon ok thank you for your help :) Does this wiring sheet helps? https://jalibu.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/advice_machine.jpg